# Plotting a Tensor in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, machine-learning

I am following the tutorial from https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/generative/dcgan

I want to be able to see the image that is being generated using plt.imshow() but for some reason the line

```
generator = make_generator_model()

noise = tf.random.normal([1, 100])
generated_image = generator(noise, training=False)
#type = tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor

plt.imshow(generated_image[0, :, :, 0], cmap='gray')
```

doesn't work for me and I get an error :

```
TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float
```

I followed a few threads on StackOverflow and tried to cast the Tensor using tf.cast, but even that didn't help.

The model as on the website is different from my code (only slightly)

```
def make_generator_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(9*9*256, use_bias=False, input_shape=(100,)))
#     model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(LeakyReLU())

    model.add(Reshape((9, 9, 256)))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 9, 9, 256) # Note: None is the batch size

    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 9, 9, 128)
#     model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(LeakyReLU())

    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(64, (3,3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 9, 9, 64)
#     model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(LeakyReLU())

    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(1, (3,3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False, activation='tanh'))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 9,9,1)

    return model
```

Comment: works fine for me, what tf version do you have?

Comment: Hi, My TF version is 1.13.1

Comment: You need to evaluate tensor first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TensorFlow 1.xx you need to [evaluate](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graphs#executing_a_graph_in_a_tfsession) output tensor.

```py
generator = make_generator_model()
noise = tf.random.normal([1, 100])
generated_image = generator(noise, training=False)

sess = tf.Session() #create session 
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) #initialize variables
image = sess.run(generated_image[0, :, :, 0]) #evaluate image tensor inside session

plt.imshow(im, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Or you can use TensorFlow 2.0 beta, where eager execution is used by default.

```py
generator = make_generator_model()
noise = tf.random.normal([1, 100])
generated_image = generator(noise, training=False)

plt.imshow(generated_image[0, :, :, 0], cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hello, this works perfectly thanks. However, if I run the cell again it gives as error:
too many indices for array